# RAM reading with CPU-Z but not Windows

Tags: memory, build

I have an ASUS Rampage III Formula with an i7-950. They both run Triple-channel memory. Max supported by the CPU is 24 GB DDR3-800/1066. The RAM that was given to me is DDR3-2400 4x8GB (totaling to 32GB).

When I use 1-3 of the sticks, I get a flat 8GB. If I use all 4, I get 16. Windows is saying 2 of 6 slots used (I used 4). If I run CPU-Z it tells me I have 32GB installed... // http://valid.x86.fr/5ui1a0

I tested the MoBo slots and all the sticks, all are functioning properly. My assumption is that it's something to do with the fact that I'm 1. Not running triple channel and 2. the freq. is too high.

If that's not the issue, please inform me of other possible causes. On top of that, I was wondering if I could possibly mix another freq. (still higher than 1066) and if so, would it work? Would it cause damage? Would there be a down side?

// Edit: Just tested every slot. See this little diagram
[CPU] D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6
The only slots that would allow the PC to boot is D2 and D4. 
I assumed because CPU-Z is reading all slots it couldn't be the motherboard.
Is this the case? Or could it still be the motherboard. If not the mobo, then I'm assuming the CPU is bad. If so, any way to tell the difference?

Comment: You need to edit your question with the same user account that you created the question with. Also, please take a couple minutes to format this question to make it easier to read. Many people will not bother to read one big solid block of text.

Comment: You should choose the slowest speeds different modules support if you mix and match. In addition check your manual for supported RAM and fix your formatting, please. Enumerations on use a period instead of a parenthesis to display properly as you will see in the preview.

Comment: Sorry, was having account issues @CharlieRB.

Comment: @Seth How would I do this? Other than that, would my assumption be correct taking into consideration the new information (cpu-z validation link) I provided?

Comment: In your BIOS. Generally it would be a good idea to check your BIOS to see whatever he's seeing if you got all the modules in. In addition which ram slots did you use? In addition which Windows 7 version are you using? Could you by chance be using a [Windows 7 Home](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)?

Comment: @Seth in BIOS it says 16 GB usable and I used the right most ones Im using Windows 10 Home

Comment: @Seth Im trying each individual slot right now, whats weird is that CPU-Z was able to detect the card in each slot so I didn't think that was an issue. After testing I've determined only 2 of the ports worked. Let me draw a little diagram. [CPU] | .|. | .|. | |  Only the 2 with the periods encasing them would let it boot. I guess this is a mobo issue?

Comment: This is a case of read your manual. There should be part where it tells you in which order you should use slots and put modules in. And as the link pointed out you won't be getting >16 GB in Windows.

Comment: @Seth Windows 10 Home supports 128GB as that link points out actually. And I understand the manual fine. The fact of the matter is no matter what combo I try it, it still only reads 16 GB in windows and BiOS but 32 in CPU-Z. I even tried mixing some RAM (to fill all 6 slots) CPU-Z again reads 40gb if I do that, windows and bios only read 16

Comment: Sorry, skipped the Windows 10 and assumed Windows 7. Well if the BIOS also tells you that its only seeing 16 gig with the modules, the modules just might be incompatible to your motherboard. Check the model of the RAM and consult your motherboard manual. The manual actually states that only modules up to 4 GB are supported. From your Diagram you'd have to put the modules into D2, D4, D6, D1 in that order, red first and black second. Maybe snap a pick of the windows screen and BIOS and add it to [the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Comment: @Seth will do. I know this RAM is dual channel and higher freq than the mobo and CPU both support. I just took out my CPU and saw some bent pins under there could be effecting the DIMM controller? I have it in the closest red one to the CPU and then middle red one

Comment: @Seth Excuse the wiring, I have to organize that after I get all this sorted. http://imgur.com/a/NvwwB All my BiOS was default and it still wasn't working. I tried modifying voltages according to some other peoples posts, still nothing. I just have 2 sticks in right now usually its the black on the left and the one in the middle/

Comment: With those two modules in that position how much RAM is detected? Dual channel doesn't really matter. It's the architecture of the modules themselves that might be an issue. I kind of do remember that way back there were problems with single and dual sided modules but there might also be some other incompatibility. How much RAM do you get in the BIOS if you use a single Module and three modules?

Comment: @Seth That's 2x8GB it's reading 16GB. If I fill up all the other slots, it still only reads those 2 slots. That's why I just took out the rest for now. Until I have some leads that is.

Comment: If you add just one more in the red slots it's also just 16 GB, right? So what happens when you use 1x8 GB and 2x4GB on the red slots? If you're still getting 16GB the slots probably work.

Comment: @Seth if I put 3x8 it still just reads 16 yes. If I put 1x8 and 2x4 in the red, it reads 12. So the 1x8 and 1x4 however CPU-Z does read them. Thinking maybe it's a DIMM controller issue?>

Comment: My guess would be that your board just doesn't like that RAM. Do you have the latest bios firmware? That could help. If you get 12 GB with 2x4 and 1x8 you're probably getting 2x4+4 so "half" of the 8 gb stick isn't used.

Comment: @Seth yes I'm on latest BIOS. Ok, maybe I'll try and see if someone has some extra triple channel at the right freq. Not really wanting to spend $150 on RAM in case that isn't the issue.

Comment: @Seth any other tests I can do in the mean time?

Comment: You won't really find triple channel kits and you don't need to. Triple channel was cool for the short time of the 1366 but pretty much dead afterwards from what I can tell. Having some other modules to test would be a good idea. My guess is still some incompatibility between those modules and your board. So I don't really have any idea what you could do to test further. Good luck!

Comment: @Seth I found some triple channels on newegg but they're around $150. I've tested 4 different kits. Basically the same results with all. I don't have any of the right frequency is the issue since I never really use 1066. But thanks!

Comment: Just don't spend 150$ on an outdated triple channel kit. The only upside of those kits is that, supposedly, they're better tuned against each other. Just get some normal modules that are supported by your motherboard. Look at the manual there is a list of supported RAM modules and pick from that. If you can get those they should work. The 1366 platform was discontinued around 2012(?) throwing that much money at it sounds like waste. Except if you really, really want those 24 GB ... 16 GB should be fine for a lot of things.